# My div is bigger than the width of the window

Tags: html, css

Is possible to place the block in the center of the page and no use JavaScript. If he is bigger than the width of the window of the browser?
How is possible do this?
Is need for the responsive page.

Comment: Please share some of your code.

Comment: We can only guess without seeing your CSS (or other code) or knowing more here...we are not good at guessing how to debug what you wrote  Answer is "Yes it is possible", now how can we assist with YOUR attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your "wider" element use in CSS

```
position: absolute;  
left: 50%;
```

and than to move it negative left to half it's width:

```
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be "or" instead of "and"? Otherwise it would shift over 100% to the left. Also, it might be helpful to state that this is CSS.

Comment: Based on the OP's markup this might not work, and I find it inappropriate that high reps. users post such an answer, and with a such a low quality question if find it even worse. Aren't we suppose to help keep the content quality on SO up?